# Parsing elements from list of list of strings

Tags: python

`list = [[1,'abc'], [2, 'bcd'], [3, 'cde']]`

I have a list that looks like above.

I want to parse the list and try to get a list that only contains the second element of all lists.

`output = ['abc','bcd','cde']`

I think I can do it by going over the whole list and add only the second element to a new list like:

```
output = []
for i in list:
    output.append(i[1])
```

something like that, but please tell me if there is a better way.

Comment: Using `list` as a variable name isn't recommended. You could always do `[x[1] for x in my_list]`, or `list(map(lambda x: x[1],my_list))` if you are in a Lispy mood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [[1,'abc'], [2, 'bcd'], [3, 'cde']]
new_l = [b for _, b in l]
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to use `itemgetter` from `operator` module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [[1,'abc'], [2, 'bcd'], [3, 'cde']]

result = list(map(itemgetter(1), l))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
```

Another not so elegant way is to use the `zip` function, take the second element from the newly created list and cast it to `list`:

```
result = list(list(zip(*l))[1])
```